# Who are the kings of peace?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I recently heard someone welcome in to their home kings of peace in the famous song Shalom Aleichem instead of angels. Who are these kings of peace? Most (if not all) kings in Tanakh were involved in lots of war, even David HaMelech. So who can they be?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Just curious - and this might be a real dumb question to those fluent in Hebrew -  is this question based on "Shalom Aleichem" being interpreted as "Shalom Melechim/Melachim"?

Comment: @Gary No it is based on those who pronounce mal'achey angels as malachei kings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be Malki-tzedek [מַלְכִּי צֶדֶק מֶלֶךְ שָׁלֵם](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8209#v=18) and those of his line who ruled that which was the City of Peace (שלם) They were repaid for greeting and honoring Avraham Avinu and serving Hashem by greeting the descendants of Avraham Avinu every shabbos who serve Hashem like Avraham did.